# Passing Parameters into an Expression Specification using LinqToSQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lambda

I want to reduce duplicate logic in a LinqToSQL query by using `Expression<Func<T,bool>>`.  We've successfully done the before using static properties like so:

```
public static Expression<Func<Document, bool>> IsActive
{
    get
    {
        return document => !document.Deleted;
    }
}

...

_workspace.GetDataSource<Document>().Where(DocumentSpecifications.IsActive)
```

However I am struggling to get this working when additional parameters need to be passed into the Expression like so:

```
public static Expression<Func<Comment, bool>> IsUnread(int userId, Viewed viewed)
{
    return
        c =>
        !c.Deleted && c.CreatedByActorID != actorId
        && (viewed == null || c.ItemCreatedDate > viewed.LastViewedDate);
}

...

// Throwing "Argument type 'System.Linq.Expression<X,bool>' is not assignable 
// to parameter type 'System.Func<X,bool>'"
return (from a in alerts
        select
        new UnreadComments
            {
               TotalNumberOfUnreadComments = 
                    a.Comments.Count(CommentSpecifications.IsUnread(actorId, a.LastView))
            })
```

How do I convert the specification so it can be accepted in this way and would it still convert to SQL correctly?

EDIT: Following Anders advice I added .Compile() to the query.  It now works correctly when unit testing in memory collections; however when LinqToSQL trys to convert it into SQL I get the following exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Count'

I've tried:

```
a.Comments.Count(CommentSpecifications.IsUnread(actorId, a.LastView).Compile())
a.Comments.AsQueryable().Count(CommentSpecifications.IsUnread(actorId, a.LastView))
```

Comment: What error do you get with the `AsQueryable()` approach? I thought it would work (if you add the parantheses).

Comment: I get the same error Anders; `System.NotSupportedException: Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Count'`

Comment: Hmm... it might help if you move the filtering to `Where()` and call a plain `Count()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the second query is executed as linq-to-objects and not as linq-to-sql. It expects a `Func<X, bool>` which is what linq-to-objects use, while linq-to-sql (or any other `IQueryable` provider) expects an uncompiled expression tree that can be translated to something else)

A quick fix is to call `Compile()` on the expression to convert it to an executable function.

```
a.Comments.Count(CommentSpecifications.IsUnread(actorId, a.LastView).Compile())
```

To be more detailed you really should figure out why that query is executed as linq-to-objects and not linq-to-sql. Especially if you expected it to be translated to efficient sql it could become a performance nightmare.

### Update

After your edit it's more obvious what's happening:

You're running the query as linq-to-objects during unit testing and as linq-to-sql later. In that case converting the expression to a `Func<>` through `Compile()` won't work as linq-to-sql won't recognize it.

### Update 2

Composing reusable part into query expression that are to be translated is hard - it confuses the translation engine. Linq-to-sql is somewhat more tolerant than linq-to-entities is, but it is nevertheless hard to get it work. A better way is often to make chaining functions that operate on `IQueryable<T>`.

```
public static IQueryable<Comment> WhereIsUnread(this IQueryable<Comment> src, int userId)
{
    return src.Where(
        c =>
        !c.Deleted && c.CreatedByActorID != actorId
        && (viewed == null || c.ItemCreatedDate > c.Alert.LastView.LastViewedDate));
}

...

return (from a in alerts
        select
        new UnreadComments
            {
               TotalNumberOfUnreadComments = 
                    a.Comments.WhereIsUnRead(actorId).Count()
            })
```

Something like that should work. Notice I've rewritten how the last viewed date is accessed, as it would otherwise fail translation to SQL when passed in as a parameter.

Comment: Great advice thank you Anders, the `.Compile()` statement worked correctly.  I'm debugging the `IEnumerable` now, it looks like it's not acting on an `IQueryable` as `a.Comments` is a sub-collection returning as an `EntitySet<Comment>`.

Comment: If you have many comments you're up to a severe performance penalty for that. It will return *all* the comments form the DB just to filter out and count some of them. Check the generated SQL: http://coding.abel.nu/2011/11/always-check-generated-sql/

Comment: Updated the question following some integration testing

Comment: Cheers for the update Anders; casting the collection using `.AsQueryable()` allows the unit tests to work without using `.Compile()` however it still cannot convert the Expression into SQL

Comment: Just read the section on how LastViewedDate is accessed, I see why it is failing now

Comment: A note on this; it works absolutely fine in situations where you are able to operate on a `IQueryable`, unfortunately `EntitySet` does not play nicely with methods.